# Ivy Bridge (Intel HD 4000) based laptop with 2 external monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

My Asus k55a sx417h has two connections for external monitors. One VGA and on HDMI. The laptop is (currently) running Windows 8 standard, as it came. It has an Ivy Bridge I5 3210m CPU.

I want to use both of these at once, to make 3 screens (including the laptop's own). According to the [spec page](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA#infosectiongraphicsspecifications) for the cpu it will support 3 displays (if I've understood it) - the Device manager states the chipset as "Intel HD Graphics 4000".

When connecting both screens in Windows 8's display properties I can choose to extend my desktop to either external monitor, but doing so disables the other - I can't enable both at once.

I don't really want to go to a DualHead2Go, or similar external box to do it, as I have the two connectors.

Is this possible? - Is it the OS or the hardware limiting me, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been able to tell on your model, you have the Intel HD 2000 GPU.  Triple-monitor requires the [HD 4000/2500](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm#3).  It would appear to be a hardware limitation put in place by your graphics chip.

Comment: According to the device manager its running "Intel HD Graphics 4000".

Answer (score 0):

Might not be possible: https://askubuntu.com/a/199038

I have a Sony Vaio Z which also has the HD 4000, with an internal LCD + one VGA port and one HDMI port. It sees both external monitors, but no matter how I mess with the Windows or Intel display settings, it won't do three monitors at the same time.